# Database: on update and on delete - how to handle?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I'm using InnoDB.

When delete and update actions occur on a particular table, I need to make certain changes to other tables. Right now, I am dealing with that through code. I'm wondering if there is a benefit to me doing this in the DB level.

Any thoughts? Pros and cons to consider? Gotchas to look out for?

Comment: are there foreign keys connecting the "causality" relationship? if not, have you thought of using triggers ?

Comment: @Dan - FKs are defined. What's the alternative to triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may want to learn about using using [MySQL Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html). Some extra links:

[Restrictions overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)

[MySQL Triggers FAQ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-triggers.html)

Comment: @Kooilnc: I'm not sure what ON DELETE and ON UPDATE does, but how different are they from triggers? Why would I choose one over the other?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. May be you ar talking about events? -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html

Comment: @Kooilnc: no, was referring to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: that's about constraints. Setting constraints on tables means you can't change or add something until something in another table is changed or added. It's the reverse, I think, of a trigger, where you modify/add something triggering an update in another table.

Comment: @Kooilnc: OK, a bit confused now. It seems like I can make the DB do certain things when certain events occur via this ON DELETE and ON UPDATE. Triggers and stored procedures are adding to the confusion for me (mostly trying to distinguish the differences).

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of doing that at the database level is that those requirements will be enforced for every user and every application. (Including you, when you're sleep-deprived and under pressure.)